# Pipes.Binary.decode - what is the StateT for?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to write a basic network server using pipes and the assorted libraries that build on it.  The intended flow would be:

get bytestring from socket -> decode using binary -> server logic goes here -> send response to socket

Which I figured would be something like:

```
fromSocket s 4096 >-> decode >-> serverLogic >-> toSocket s
```

pipes-binary has a `decode` and a `decodeMany`, but I am not sure I understand the difference, and I don't know how to use `decode`.  Why does `decodeMany` take the upstream pipe as an argument instead of being chained off of it with `>->`?  And how do you use `decode`, what is the `StateT` for and what should my pipe chain end up looking like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StateT (Producer a m r) m x` idiom comes from [`pipes-parse`'s "Low-level Parsers"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-parse-2.0.2/docs/Pipes-Parse.html#v%3adraw). It typically means that the library is using `draw` and `unDraw` to pull values off a `Producer` and return them if they're unused. It's an essential component of parsing where failure might occur. It also requires the `StateT` layer to indicate that a pipe is being selectively drained and refilled in a stateful manner.

```
-- | Draw one element from the underlying Producer, 
-- returning Left if the Producer is empty
draw :: Monad m => StateT (Producer a m r) m (Either r a)

-- | Push back an element onto the underlying Producer
unDraw :: Monad m => a -> StateT (Producer a m r) m ()
```

So what does that mean for `decode` and `decodeMany`? If we look at some simplified types of those functions

```
-- for (Monad m, Binary b)

decode     :: StateT (Producer ByteString m r) m (Maybe b)
decodeMany :: Producer ByteString m r 
           -> Producer' b m (Either (Producer ByteString m r) r)
```

We first see that `decode` is `drawing` off enough `ByteString` chunks from a `Producer ByteString` statefully so as to try to parse a `b`. Since the chunk boundary on the `ByteString`s may not align with a parse boundary it's important to do this in `StateT` so that the leftover chunks can be `unDraw`-ed back into the `Producer`.

`decodeMany` builds atop `decode` and attempts to repeatedly `decode` `b`s off the input Producer returning a "continuation" `Producer` of leftover `ByteString`s on failure.

Long story short, due to a need to `unDraw` leftover `ByteString` chunks, we can just compose these things together into a chain with `(>->)`. If you want to do that, you can use something like `decodeMany` to transform a producer and then chain the result, but you'll want to handle error cases carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I want to complement J. Abrahamson's answer by answering your other question about why the decoder is not a `Pipe`.

The difference between a `Pipe` with a type like:

```
pipe :: Pipe a b m r
```

... and function between `Producer`s like (I call these "getter"s):

```
getter :: Producer a m r -> Producer b m r
```

... is that a `Pipe` can be used to transform `Producer`s, `Consumer`s, and other `Pipe`s:

```
(>-> pipe) :: Producer a m r -> Producer b m r

(>-> pipe) :: Pipe x a m r -> Pipe x b m r

(pipe >->) :: Consumer b m r -> Consumer a m r

(pipe >->) :: Pipe b y m r -> Pipe a y m r
```

... whereas a "getter" can only transform `Producer`s.  Some things cannot be modeled correctly using `Pipe`s and leftovers are one of those things.

`conduit` purports to model leftovers using `Conduit`s (the `conduit` analog of `Pipe`s) but it gets this wrong.  I've put together a simple example showing why.  First, just implement a `peek` function for `conduit`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List (isolate, sourceList)

peek :: Monad m => Sink a m (Maybe a)
peek = do
    ma <- await
    case ma of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just a  -> leftover a
    return ma
```

This works as expected for simple cases like this:

```
source :: Monad m => Source m Int
source = sourceList [1, 2]

sink1 :: Show a => Sink a IO ()
sink1 = do
    ma1 <- peek
    ma2 <- peek
    lift $ print (ma1, ma2)
```

This will return the first element of the source twice:

```
>>> source $$ sink1
(Just 1,Just 1)
```

... but if you compose a `Conduit` upstream of a `Sink`, any leftovers that the sink pushes back are irreversibly lost:

```
sink2 :: Show a => Sink a IO ()
sink2 = do
    ma1 <- isolate 10 =$ peek
    ma2 <- peek
    lift $ print (ma1, ma2)
```

Now the second `peek` incorrectly returns `2`:

```
>>> source $$ sink2
(Just 1,Just 2)
```

Also, note that `pipes-parse` just got a new major version released today, which simplifies the API and adds an extensive tutorial that you can read [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-parse-3.0.0/docs/Pipes-Parse-Tutorial.html).

This new API correctly propagates leftovers further upstream.  Here is the analogous example for `pipes`:

```
import Lens.Family.State.Strict (zoom)
import Pipes
import Pipes.Parse
import Prelude hiding (splitAt)

parser :: Show a => Parser a IO ()
parser = do
    ma1 <- zoom (splitAt 10) peek
    ma2 <- peek
    lift $ print (ma1, ma2)

producer :: Monad m => Producer Int m ()
producer = each [1, 2]
```

Even though the first `peek` is also limited to the first 10 values, it correctly undraws the first value and makes it available to the second `peek`:

```
>>> evalStateT parser producer
(Just 1,Just 1)
```

Conceptually, the reason why `pipes-parse` "thinks in terms of `Producer`s" is because otherwise the concept of leftovers is not clearly defined.  If you don't clearly define what your source is, you can't clearly articulate where leftovers values should go.  This is why `Pipe`s and `Consumer`s do not lend themselves well to tasks that require leftovers.

Comment: I just thought about this given your `Pipe -> Pipe` being called a Getter, but if you look at Pipes as the obvious Profunctors that they are, can you see that Getter as a kind of pure Profunctor lens?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson If you study the new `pipes-parse` API you will see that it uses lenses between producers as parsing transducers.  Functions between `Producer`s are just the special case where those lenses are `Getter`s.